# How to remove my github repository (button error)

Tags: github, github-pages

Button is not pressed even after entering right content, how can I solve it?

[image: I attached a related photo.]

Comment: Which button are you talking about? Please add more details and context.

Comment: I can imagine which button you mean, and if this is true, this sounds more like a question for the GitHub technical support than for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @mkrieger1 thank you for answer, i will solve it with your advice.

Answer (score 2):

There may be several reasons the remove button isn't working:

- There are common compatibility errors with the Safari browser. If you are using it, consider trying using Chrome or Firefox for this task.
- Press F12 -> Console -> There may be a Javascript error caused by script blockers loaded on your browser.

Consider detailing your question with screenshots of the problem and details about your browser.